# Possible to force merge a feature branch in git/GitHub

Tags: git, github, merge

I've got a GitHub repo that loosely follows git-flow. There are two long-standing branches: `master` and `develop`. A feature branch (`feature/one`)  was cut off of `develop` some time ago. A PR exists to merge `feature/one` back into `develop`, however there are *lots* of merge conflicts.

I'm 100% certain that I want all the changes in `feature/one` to trump and override any conflicts from `develop`. Is there any way to force git to just say "*Hey, anything that's conflicting in `feature/one` and `develop`, just use the changes from `feature/one`*" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During merging from `feature/one` into `develop` branch, you can use this:

```
git checkout develop
git merge -X theirs feature/one
```

The long form for `-X theirs` is `--strategy-option=theirs`. So the longer form is:

```
git merge --strategy-option=theirs feature/one
```

You can refer the `git merge` [man page](https://gitirc.eu/git-merge.html).

Comment: Saved my life, thanks for the extra context on the long form!!